# No module named registration.forms in django-facebook

Tags: python, django, facebook, authentication, django-facebook

I'm using the `django-facebook` library (https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook) for authentication using Facebook.

However, when I go to the sample template to test registrations at `/facebook/connect` and try to connect, I get an `ImportError`:

> No module named registration.forms

Does anybody know what this error is about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to install [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/).